# Plotting Python lists - Integers and Datetimes

Tags: python, datetime, graph

I am writing a program that analyses historical data, I'm attempting to plot said data to show a relationship. I have hit a point where I'm unsure where I'm going wrong.

```
def somefunction():
    with open(path + '/120410_69.csv', 'r') as BCRWC:
    readCSV = csv.reader(BCRWC, delimiter=',')

    BCRWCdata = []
    BCRWCresults = []
    BCRWCdatetimes = []

    for row in readCSV:
        BCRWCdata.append(row)

    BCRWCdata.pop(0) #Removing headers from data

    result = float(row[2]) #Integers
    datetime = row[8] #Strings in format 13/02/2018  00:00:00

    BCRWCresults.append(result)
    BCRWCdatetimes.append(datetime)

fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot(x=BCRWCdatetimes, y=BCRWCresults)
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Raw Water Colour Result")
plt.ylim(15, 70)
plt.show()

return BCRWCresults
return BCRWCdatetimes
```

I understand I need to convert the long list of strings (BCRWCdatetimes) into datetime objects (I think) but I can't figure out how, I also need to spread the data out evenly along the x axis so that the dates are not overlapping. This is the graph as I have it right now -

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you show us the beginning of your two lists? i.e. post `BCRWCdatetimes[:10]` and `BCRWCresults[:10]`

Comment: Ah, the lists only contain one item so maybe I have an indentation problem somewhere. [16.1] [13/02/2008 08:20]

Comment: That could explain why you have only one data point in your plot... the issue is in the way in which you populate your lists; try doing it in a separate loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playing with a made up list in the format you posted, I was able to plot it the way you want it using this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime
# Make up some data
BCRWCresults = [16.12, 43.2, 62.1, 15.4, 18.7]
BCRWCdatetimes = ['13/02/2008 08:20', '13/03/2008 08:20', '13/04/2008 08:20', '13/05/2008 08:20', '13/02/2008 12:20']

# Convert to datetime
BCRWCdatetimes = [datetime.datetime.strptime(i, '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M') for i in BCRWCdatetimes]

# for the x-axis labels, get just the month and year of your datetimes:
date_months = [str(i.month) + '-' + str(i.year) for i in dates]

fig = plt.figure()
plt.plot_date(x=dates, y=BCRWCresults)
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.xticks(dates, date_months, rotation=90)
plt.ylabel("Raw Water Colour Result")
plt.ylim(15, 70)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Depending on how many dates you want to display on your x-axis, you can mess around with the `plt.xticks` argument